# Showing json response in TextView

Tags: java, android, json

I have a Json response :

```
{
    "action":"true",
        "0":{
    "_id":"58ca7f56e13823497175ee47"
    }
}
```

and I want to show the **_id** value in a `TextView`.

**I tried this :**

```
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, reg_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray Jarray  = object.getJSONArray("0");
                String message = object.getString("_id");

                txtstorename.setText(message);
```

I can see Json response in Android Monitor but I got nothing in my `TextView`!
what is the problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to use `getJSONObject("0")` instead of `getJSONArray` because `0` is not an array.
An array would be indicated by `[ /* stuff here */ ]`, which you do not have.

You have a Json object containing `action` and `0`, `action` is a String, and `0` is an object.

In the `0` object you then have an `_id` field which you are trying to access.

---

So in your case something like the following:

```
// get the object
JSONObject object0  = object.getJSONObject("0");
String message = object0.getString("_id");
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be the correct way

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
JSONObject object1 = object.get("0");
String message = object1.get("_id");
txtstorename.setText(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, reg_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONObject jsonObj= object.getJSONObject("0");
                String message = jsonObj.getString("_id");    
                txtstorename.setText(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `JsonObject` into `JsonArray`. thats why there is problem.

**replace this line:**

```
JSONArray Jarray  = object.getJSONArray("0");
```

**with This**

```
JsonObject jsonObject = object.getJSONObject("0");
```

Answer (score 0):

When receiving JSON Object as response use JsonObjectRequest instead of StringRequest

```
JsonObjectRequest request= new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,url, null,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){@Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj= response.getJSONObject("0");
            String message = jsonObj.getString("_id");    
            txtstorename.setText(message);},null);
```