# Cannot split json response in android

Tags: java, android, json

I'm getting a json response from server. Here is my json  :

```
 {
  "result": 1,
  "IsActive": true,
  "Type": 0,
  "FirstName": "John",
  "roleId": 6300,
  "MinTotalPriceOrder": 0,
  "PhoneNumberConfirmed": false,
  "Cell": "09382665250",
  "StartDate": "2015-09-30T11:41:58",
  "DepotId": 393,
  "mlm": null,
  "revoked": false
}
```

now i want to split them. i mean i want to put "FirstName" from server in a String or show it in a textview. but It shows the whole json in the textview!
here is my java code :

```
 StringRequest strRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                    new Response.Listener<String>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response)
                        {
                            try {
                                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);
                                JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(1);
                                String result = jObject.getString("FirstName");
                                textview.setText(result);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
```

what's the problem?

Comment: It is not JSONArray you getting JSONObject

Comment: Code looks ok. You should print the `response` and `result` and see if it's as expected. Also note that arrays are 0-indexed. So `getJSONObject(1);` will be the *second* item.

Comment: `now i want to split them. ` You mean: "i want to parse it".

Comment: @greenapps eagle eye

Comment: JSONObject mJsonObject = new JSONObject(responseString);                                           
mJsonObject.getString("FirstName");                                                                               This is enough i guess

Comment: Parsing json should be easy using a POJO generated here : http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ then simply using getters and setters to access values

Comment: didn't you asked similar Q here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42873254/showing-json-response-in-textview?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
StringRequest strRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                    new Response.Listener<String>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response)
                        {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);

                                String result = jObject.getString("FirstName");
                                textview.setText(result);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: `Please accept my answer.` Please do not ask such things for yourself. Makes a bad impression.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get it by JSONObject not by JSONArray because that is json object. Try the following code.

```
StringRequest strRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
  new Response.Listener<String>()
  {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response)
    {
        try {
             JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);

             String result = jObject.getString("result");
             String isActive =  jObject.getString("IsActive");
             String Type = jObject.getString("Type");
             String FirstName =  jObject.getString("FirstName");
             String roleId = jObject.getString("roleId");
             String MinTotalPriceOrder = jObject.getS tring("MinTotalPriceOrder");
             String PhoneNumberConfirmed = jObject.getString("PhoneNumberConfirmed");
             String Cell =  jObject.getString("Cell");
             String StartDate = jObject.getString("StartDate");
             String DepotId =  jObject.getString("DepotId");
             String mlm = jObject.getString("mlm");
             String revoked = jObject.getString("revoked");
             textview.setText(FirstName);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
            }
       }
}
```